# Rails array sort

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have in rails this array:

```
@array = [{'82'=>'1'}, {'81'=>'0'},{'32'=>'12'}]
```

How can I sort it to have that result? I want to have this:

```
@array = [{'32'=>'12'}, {'82'=>'1'},{'81'=>'0'}]
```

and next - how then I can get @array[0] hash key (32)

This is an array of hash where hash is {'user_id'=>'counter'}

Comment: Your example doesn't fit your description of what you want. The array you provided as example output is neither sorted by value, nor by key.

Comment: Then what is "12" and "1" and "0" in this hashes?

Comment: If anything, they are sorted in descending order, which nowhere you state is what you want.

Comment: I'm trying to help you by making you clarify your question. If you check the existing answers, you'll see both misunderstood what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will sort the array by value, in descending order, in place:

```
array.sort! { |h1, h2| h2.values.first <=> h1.values.first }
```

It can also be done with `sort_by!` followed by `reverse!`.

```
array.sort_by! { |h| h.values } .reverse!
```

Then, these will get you the first value and first key, respectively:

```
array.first.values.first
array.first.keys.first
```

Answer (score 0):

Just append keys.sort to the end of the array. Use @array.keys.sort

Answer (score 0):

```
@array.sort { |x,y| x.keys.first <=> y.keys.first }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`Enumerable#sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by), and [`Array#reverse!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-reverse-21) to change the order.

```
> @array.sort_by { |h| h.values.first }.reverse!
 => [{"32"=>"12"}, {"82"=>"1"}, {"81"=>"0"}]
```

Comment: Please try to provide a brief reason for the downvote!